# SpawnObject for ak(Clone) (UnityEngine.GameObject), NetworkServer is not active. Cannot spawn objects without an active server

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-mirror

helloI'm making an object in Unity that gives players random weapons when they hover over it, but it always gives me this warning and doesn't create it.

```
[ClientRpc]
public void spawnTime()
{
    StartCoroutine(spawn());
}
public IEnumerator spawn()
{
    Debug.Log("oldu");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    int a = Random.Range(0, guns.Length);
    GameObject gun =Instantiate(guns[a], spawnPoint.position,Quaternion.identity);
    gun.transform.SetParent(transform);
    NetworkServer.Spawn(gun);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of you are calling the spawn function from client. You should call it in server.

```
[Server]
public void spawnTime()
{
    StartCoroutine(spawn());
}

[Server]
public IEnumerator spawn()
{
    Debug.Log("oldu");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    int a = Random.Range(0, guns.Length);
    GameObject gun =Instantiate(guns[a], 
    spawnPoint.position,Quaternion.identity);
    gun.transform.SetParent(transform);
    NetworkServer.Spawn(gun);


    uint gunNetId = gun.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().netId;
    uint parentNetId = transform.root.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().netId;
    RpcSetParent(parentNetId, gunNetId);
}

[ClientRpc]
void RpcSetParent(uint parentNetId, uint childNetId)
{
    Transform child = NetworkClient.spawned[childNetId].transform;
    Transform parent = NetworkClient.spawned[parentNetId].transform;

    child.SetParent(parent);
}
```

Be sure that you are calling the **spawnTime()** function from something running in server and networked object. You can filter it something like:

```
Start(){
    NetworkIdentity nid = transform.root.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>();

    if(nid.isServer)
    {
        spawnTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried but it didn't work

Comment: is there any other warning/error on the server logs, or any other details?

Comment: The code didn't give an error but didn't work either.

Comment: ok. most probably everything is fine except parenting state. you need to apply parenting state on client side-too; you can check your hierarchy to see that your guns instance exists. I will update the answer to explain how to parent check it out again.

Comment: you can check it

Comment: yes it worked. thank you very much.

Comment: good to hear, you are welcome :)